# AppCode opens .storyboard files as plain XML

Tags: ios, appcode

I'm using AppCode 3.3. When I click on a .storyboard file, it doesn't open UI Designer. I can't install UI Designer plugin because of version of AppCode (latest compatible is 141.x, I'm using 143).

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JetBrains made UI Designer a plugin that had to be loaded separately. I guess it's because it's very hard to follow Apple's changes in formats and features for storyboard files. Actually, the plugin doesn't support Swift and macOS.

JetBrains made a statement on their site why it was removed, but the link isn't active anymore.
The plugin [is still available](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/objc/plugin/7807-appcode-ui-designer) for older versions.

Why not use Xcode for this? While Xcode Interface Builder has its weak spots, it is one of the better parts of Xcode. But AppCode is much better for coding.

Comment: What if I don't want to allocate 1.5GB more RAM just to open a storyboard file? What if I have a single monitor, opening two programs to work on one project is a workflow bottleneck.

Comment: You can get used to it, at least I did. But I agree: not really great. But storyboards aren't that great anyway.

Comment: Just stop using storyboards. They are usually blank because of whitelabeling, no good localization support and they are xml files that changes with every Xcode version. Use SnapKit for constraints and do UI from code.